# Robots.txt and Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, seo, robots.txt

I am trying to disallow certain parts of a site instead of the whole thing. 
I am relatively new to this so if someone walk me through it I will appreciate it.

I know that you can Disallow: /page1.cfm from crawlers but what if I want to disallow just a part of that page such as a link or a contact form that exists on that page? Is this functionality even possible?

Based on some forums I was reading recently, the "nofollow" function is not really working anymore since the crawlers are becoming smarter. (i don't know how credible that forum was, so if anyone has a better source please share)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also keep in mind that _annoying or malicious_ crawlers can (and often) ignore this information entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use nofollow, you'll loose linkjuice on your page.

Robots.txt are just a hint for crawler, half of the time with disalow rules if they already have find the page they still visit it and index it.

Use .htaccess rules to ban or block the access to this pages.
Or crypt your link with a complex .js (base64_encode() + str_rot13() encoding should be enough to lost the crawler)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute "nofollow" in the meta tag to hide the information on the page. Google wrote that they do not pass on the links labeled "nofollow." More information about this and examples you can find here:
[Robots.txt tutorial](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/) and [Google support](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569)
Hope this helps